# What happens when start value < end value with range() cmd in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, range, increment

We know that `range(m,n)` gives `m, m+1, m+2... n - 1` with the incrementer defaulting to `1`. However, what happens when `m >= n`?

Example 1:

`for j in range(i+1, 4)` where `i = 3` gives `range(3+1, 4)` or `range(4, 4)` such that `m = 4` and `n = 4` and `m > n - 1` (where `m = startvalue` and `n = stopvalue`).

Example 2:

`for j in range(i+1, 4)` where `i = 4` gives `range(4+1, 4)` or `range(5, 4)` such that `m = 5` and `n = 4` and `m > n - 1` (again, where `m = startvalue` and `n = stopvalue`).

Would it just be that `incrementer = -1` instead of `incrementer = 1` by default in such a case, or would an error be thrown, or would nothing happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: If only there was a way to find out.

Comment: Why didn't you give it a try and observe, what happens? If `m` >= `n`, the loop with `range(m, n)` is ignored without an error message. Unless, you specify a negative step - `range(10, 1, -1)` counts backwards.

Comment: @timgeb I didn't run the code myself because I'm preparing for a computer science final and I was trying to figure it out before running it and getting an answer. On the final, we'll be given code and told to say what the result will be.

Comment: @karathrace99 where's the difference between us or the interpreter giving you the answer?

Comment: @timgeb This is one part of a much larger problem. I only was looking for a hint on this one tiny part without getting an answer to the whole thing, which is what running it would give me.

Comment: @Piinthesky Okay, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @karathrace99 You could have written the tiny part `range(4,3)` into the interpreter in order to get the solution of that tiny part. Moreover you did not ask for a hint in your question, but for the solution.

Comment: I hope, you listen to @timgeb words. You spent more time here than typing `m = 7
n = 5
for i in range(m, n):
    print(i)`

Answer (score -1):

The range command returns a list of values. If your 'start' is greater than your 'end' value, an empty list is returned.

The default increment value is positive 1.  You can, however, use a third argument as the increment value. You can pass it as -1, and then the range() will return a decreasing value, as you're looking for.

This is for Python 2. In Py3, things are similar yet different.

Comment: While this answer is correct, I downvoted it because OP shows a level of lazyness that should not be supported. Many other disagree with downvotes like this, I stand by them.

Comment: @Gary02127 Okay, that makes sense. I was thinking it would probably come up empty without a third argument in range(), but wanted to make sure I got the semantics right for my exam. Thank you!

Comment: @timgeb I've used stackoverflow to supplement CSC my education for a long time. I am using it here to clarify a key semantic with the range() fn I didn't understand and need to before moving forward. If I had just run the interpreter, that wouldn't have really helped me learn; it isn't going to explain any of it (tell me the "why"), it'll just produce an answer I don't understand. I'll continue to use this forum this way, even when some don't support beginners. The community is for everyone.

Comment: @karathrace99 In addition to testing in an interpreter, you can also [read the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) ... It is clearly stated that : "If step is positive, the last element is the largest start + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop. step must not be zero (or else ValueError is raised)"